# Invoke-Command to multiple servers, what is the current server?

Tags: powershell

Below is my striped down code.
How can I determine what the current server is when parsing to Write-Host? With other words, what can I use instead of "$CURRENTSERVER"?

```
$servers = SERVER1,SERVER2,SERVER3

Try
{
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $servers -ErrorAction Stop -ScriptBlock{CODE}
}
Catch
{
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow "[WARNING] Cannot connect to $CURRENTSERVER"
}
```

The information is there somewhere, if I run the command without try-catch I get

```
[SERVER3] Connecting to remote server SERVER3 failed with the following error message : WinRM cannot process the request.
```

Comment: `Write-Host $_.Exception.Message` perhaps?

Comment: That worked to get the message, thank you! Now ho do I only get the text between the brackets [SERVER3]?

Comment: EDIT: I found the property: `$_.TargetObject`

Answer (score 1):

I found the parameter for the information:
`$_.TargetObject`